# Do we hear about the nun Sheldon Cooper saved in the Big Bang Theory again?

Tags: character, the-big-bang-theory

In The Big Bang Theory S04 episode 21, Sheldon Cooper at one point states "I saved a nuns life, why am I being punished?".

Do we ever find out more about this or does the character pop into the series at any point? I am struggling to find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's explained in the same episode. Sheldon's talking about an elderly nun whom he saved by giving her mouth-to-mouth resuscitation in a bus.

> **Penny**: Sheldon, have you ever kissed a girl?
> **Sheldon**: Other than my mother, my sister and my Meemaw, no.
> But in the interest of full disclosure, I was once on a bus and had to give
> **mouth-to-mouth resuscitation to an elderly nun who passed out from heat exhaustion**.
> Every year I get a Christmas card from her, signed with far too many
> X’s and O’s.

You can refer the [script](https://subslikescript.com/series/The_Big_Bang_Theory-898266/season-4/episode-21-The_Agreement_Dissection) here.